# When an iPhone app uses Face ID does the app itself see your face (i.e. front cam)?

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, face-id

When an iPhone app asks for and uses your Face ID, does that mean the app has access to your iPhone's front camera? Or does it mean the app only receives a true/false value from the iPhone saying whether it is you or not?

Example of notification:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The app does not get access to the iPhone's front camera when you agree to this popup.

The app is only allowed to use Face ID functionality. This means that it will know only whether or not the device owner is present. The app can decide whether that must be determined by Face ID, or if the user can choose to enter their pass code instead.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/logging_a_user_into_your_app_with_face_id_or_touch_id

Comment: Note also that Face ID doesn't use the front camera anyway, it uses a dot projector, an infrared flood illuminator, and an infrared camera - see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face_ID) or [Apple's explainer](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208108).